# What is the command to replace blocks in Minecraft PE?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

Say I want to replace my grass blocks with quartz, I have tried so many commands but none seem to work!

Answer (score 2):

**Use the `fill` command.**

```
/fill <from: x y z> <to: x y z> <tileName: Block> [tileData: int]
```

`<from: x y z>` and `<to: x y z>`: The coordinates of the opposite corners of the area where the blocks will be filled.

`<tileName: Block>`: The block you want to fill the area with.

`[tileData: int]`: Optional part where you put a number to specify what data value you want the block in `<tileName: Block>` to be.

**Examples**

Fill an area from `0 1 2` to `3 4 5` with orange wool (the data value is 1):

```
/fill 0 1 2 3 4 5 wool 1
```

Fill an area from `16 37 47` to `-56 34 1` with stone:

```
/fill 16 37 47 -56 34 1 stone
```

**Sources**
[Commands/fill on Minecraft Gamepedia](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands/fill)
[Wool on Minecraft Gamepedia](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Wool)
[Stone on Minecraft Gamepedia](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Stone)

Answer (score 1):

The command is a run off of the `/fill` command. You would type
`/fill (x)(y)(z)(x)(y)(z) quartz_block 1 replace grass`. Mind the fill limit.