# How do I change grass blocks within a set region to magma blocks?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I'm wanting to change grass to magma on my Bedrock Edition, Nintendo Switch world to make a Skyblock challenge sort of thing but so far every command I've tried just says "invalid command". Does anyone here know what I should be doing differently?

PS The range is from x256 z256 to x-256 z-256 if that changes anything.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a utility to replace one block type with another within a region?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/27771/is-there-a-utility-to-replace-one-block-type-with-another-within-a-region)

Comment: @pppery Will that be sufficiently helpful for Bedrock Edition?

Comment: Yes, `/fill` works in bedrock as well. https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Commands/fill

Comment: Better duplicate target: [What is the command to replace blocks in Minecraft PE?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/341445/what-is-the-command-to-replace-blocks-in-minecraft-pe/341634#341634)

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`fill`](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands/fill) command.

```
/fill x1 y1 z1 x2 y2 z2 magma 0 replace grass
```

When using the `fill` command, there is a limit of 32,768 blocks, so you will need to use multiple fill commands. If the fill volume is 1 block high, using the following coordinates in 9 commands should work (where `y` is the y-coordinate):

- `-256 y -256 -76 y -76`
- `-256 y -75 -76 y 104`
- `-256 y 106 -76 y 256`
- `-75 y -256 105 y -76`
- `-75 y -75 105 y 104`
- `-75 y 106 105 y 256`
- `106 y -256 256 y -76`
- `106 y -75 256 y 104`
- `106 y 106 256 y 256`

If the fill volume is more than 1 block high, you will need to divide it into even more fill commands. 181<sup>2</sup> is 32,761, so dividing an area into 181 × 181 squares will work. If you have an even larger volume, 32<sup>3</sup> is 32,768.

Comment: thank you so much! if i had a way to pay you, i would.

Comment: @user237872 You're welcome. On Arqade, you can also show your thanks by upvoting my answer and accepting it, which would indicate that your question has been solved and also give me some reputation. You also gain 2 reputation by accepting an answer.

Comment: @user237872 I forgot to mention that you can accept an answer by clicking the green checkmark.