# Which command would I use to clear an area of one type of block in MCBE?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I'm trying to clear an area of stone and nothing else. Is there a command I can use for this?

Comment: https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Commands/fill

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the command to replace blocks in Minecraft PE?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/341445/what-is-the-command-to-replace-blocks-in-minecraft-pe)

Answer (score 1):

```
/fill 0 0 0 10 10 10 air 0 replace stone 0
```

That command makes all stone air.
Leave the last number out (i.e. `/fill 0 0 0 10 10 10 air 0 replace stone`) to replace all blocks of that ID, in that example removing the 0 would replace stone, granite, etc.. Note the data value after the first ID is absolutely necessary.
Syntax:

```
/fill <from: x y z> <to: x y z> <tileName: Block> <tileData: int> replace [replaceTileName: Block] [replaceDataValue: int]
```