# How do I replace the water in a 128 x 108 blocks sea base?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I’m making a sea base in creative and it’s absolutely massive. 108 x 128 blocks. I’ve tried using `/fill` command but it says the area is too big.

Is there anything else I can do besides sponges? I’m on console so no WorldEdit either.

Comment: How tall is the area? A single block height (technically 2 or 3) should be fine for that size, although rather tedious.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the command to replace blocks in Minecraft PE?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/341445/what-is-the-command-to-replace-blocks-in-minecraft-pe)

Answer (score 1):

use this command:

```
/fill <coordinate1> <coordinate2> <block> <action>
/fill <<x1> <y1> <z1>> <<x2> <y2> <z2>> <block> <action>
```

- use for x1, y1, z1 the coordinates of one block
- use for x2, y2, z2 the coordinates of a second block diagonaly from the first
- set in as block 'air' or 'water' what you want

That would be something like that:

```
/fill 100 20 100 500 80 500 air
```

**if it gives an error that the volume is more than 32 768 block, you have to split the area in multiple subareas to use the command**

> please give a feedback if it works or not and please mark the answer as solved to help others

Have a great day!

Answer (score -1):

Although the area may be too large for one `/fill` command, you can remove the water in stages.

*Keep in mind that the /fill command has a maximum fill limit of 32 768 blocks. To find out how many /fill commands you’ll need, just do:*
**Volume of area** divided by **32 768**

Comment: Assuming you can perfectly fill 32768 blocks every time, and you can't do 0.X of a `/fill` (x is any number)

Comment: @aytimothy if any water is left over, you could just finish it off with sponge… this might not work if they want a perfectly rectangular space…