# How do I replace spruce leaves with oak leaves in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I'm unhappy with the way I built something in Minecraft, and want to replace the spruce leaves with oak leave to match the rest of the build, but I do not know how to. Can someone tell me what the block data is?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the command to replace blocks in Minecraft PE?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/341445/what-is-the-command-to-replace-blocks-in-minecraft-pe)

Answer (score 1):

`/fill` command fills a region with some blocks or replaces specific blocks with other ones. Especially for your case, execute this:

`/fill ~ ~ ~ ~10 ~10 ~10 leaves 0 replace leaves 1`

Where `~ ~ ~` is the first position of the region, and `~10 ~10 ~10` is the opposite position of the previous one. `leaves 0` and `leaves 1` are for oak and spruce leaves respectively. [Syntax of the `fill` command](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands/fill#Syntax).

---

Block data is needed for differing various block variations from each other. For example, whether waterlogged the block or not. You should check block data for each block separately. [The block data of leaves](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Leaves#Data_values).