# What is the command to remove certain blocks?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I need to know what the command is for removing specific blocks, if I remember I once used a `/execute` command in a command block to remove certain blocks but I forgot it and I’m no command block expert.

Comment: Maybe it was a [fill replace](https://www.digminecraft.com/game_commands/fill_replace_water.php)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the command to replace blocks in Minecraft PE?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/341445/what-is-the-command-to-replace-blocks-in-minecraft-pe)